# Which option should $A$ prefer so that the probability of his winning the match is higher?

Tags: probability

Suppose the probability for $A$ to win a game against $B$ is $0.4$.If $A$ has the option of playing either a ''best of three games'' or a ''best of five games'' match against $B$,which option should $A$ prefer so that the probability of his winning the match is higher?(No game ends in a draw.)

I could not start this question,no idea how to tackle such best of three or best of five type questions.

Comment: Commonsense suggests that if you have a less than even chance of winning, the shorter the series of matches, the better your chances, however, you need to compute using the binomial distribution, which you must surely have learnt. What is your specific difficulty ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint*

To win a best of $(2n-1)$ series, you need to win at least $n$ matches

Answer (score 1):

As true blue anil noted in a comment, you could work this out using the binomial distribution. However, there's a straightforward argument that doesn't require any calculation. Consider a match of $5$ games, and also consider a match consisting only of the first $3$ of the $5$ games. If both matches have the same winner, it doesn't matter whether you only play the $3$ or go on to play all $5$. If they have different winners, then the player who won more of the $5$ games would have won the $5$-game match but lost the $3$-game match. Thus $5$-game matches are better for the player who is more likely to win more of the $5$ games, i.e. the player who is more likely to win a game, and $3$-game matches are better for the other player.